# How to add alert message if i not selected the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

when i click the Select working days / hours Checkbox the list of days checkbox will be displayed if i not selected any of the day checkbox in that case alert message displayed should be "`shop closed`"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $("#btnCheckdays").click(function(){
           var ChkSUN = $('#ChkSUN:checked').val();
           var ChkMON = $('#ChkMON:checked').val();

            var SunStart = $("#ddlSunStart option:selected").val();
            var SunEnd = $("#ddlSunEnd option:selected").val();
            var MonStart = $("#ddlMonStart option:selected").val();
            var MonEnd = $("#ddlMonEnd option:selected").val();

            alert('Day ' + ChkSUN + ' Start Time is :'+ SunStart +' End Time is :'+ SunEnd +'');
            alert('Day ' + ChkMON + ' Start Time is :'+ MonStart +' End Time is :'+ MonEnd +'');
            });

           });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/9z6ttkvo/15/)

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Is there a reason for showing several alert boxes and having the user painfully _okay_ through all 7 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$('#ChkSUN').is(":checked")` to see if either of the checkboxes are checked or not:

```js
$('#addweekhours').click(function() {
  $('#showweekhours').slideToggle("fast");
});
$('.sun').click(function() {
  $('#Sun').slideToggle("fast");
});
$('.mon').click(function() {
  $('#Mon').slideToggle("fast");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnCheckdays").click(function() {
    var ChkSUN = $('#ChkSUN:checked').val();
    var ChkMON = $('#ChkMON:checked').val();
    if ($('#ChkSUN').is(":checked") || ($('#ChkMON').is(":checked"))) {
      var SunStart = $("#ddlSunStart option:selected").val();
      var SunEnd = $("#ddlSunEnd option:selected").val();
      var MonStart = $("#ddlMonStart option:selected").val();
      var MonEnd = $("#ddlMonEnd option:selected").val();

      alert('Day ' + ChkSUN + ' Start Time is :' + SunStart + ' End Time is :' + SunEnd + '');
      alert('Day ' + ChkMON + ' Start Time is :' + MonStart + ' End Time is :' + MonEnd + '');
    } else {
      alert("Shop closed.");
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.option-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 13.33333px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  background: #cbd1d8;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.option-input:hover {
  background: #9faab7;
}

.option-input:checked {
  background: #40e0d0;
}

.option-input:checked::before {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '✔';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16.66667px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.option-input:checked::after {
  -webkit-animation: click-wave 0.65s;
  -moz-animation: click-wave 0.65s;
  animation: click-wave 0.65s;
  background: #40e0d0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.option-input.radio {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.option-input.radio::after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

select,
.form-control,
textarea,
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="week"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="color"],
.uneditable-input {
  color: #999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tg-formsection">
  <div class="tg-heading-border tg-small">
    <h3>Add Clinic Business Hours</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <div class="tg-docschedule tg-haslayout">
        <form class="form-docschedule" method="POST">
          <fieldset class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label><h4>Business Hours:</h4></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <label>
<input type="radio" id="fullhours" class="option-input radio" />
<span style="font-size:20px;">24 hours x 7 days</span>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="addweekhours" class="option-input radio" />
<span style="font-size:20px">Select working days / hours</span>
</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="showweekhours" style="display:none;">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="ChkSUN" type="checkbox" value="Sunday" runat="server" class="single sun option-input checkbox" name="days" /><span class="sun" style="font-size:20px;"> Sunday</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="Sun" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <select ID="ddlSunStart" runat="server" class="form-control">
<option value="Satrt">Starts at</option>
<option value="1:00">1:00</option>
<option value="1:30">1:30</option>
<option value="2:00">2:00</option>
<option value="2:30">2:30</option>
<option value="3:00">3:00</option>
<option value="3:30">3:30</option>
<option value="4:00">4:00</option>
<option value="4:30">4:30</option>
<option value="5:00">5:00</option>
<option value="5:30">5:30</option>
<option value="6:00">6:00</option>
<option value="6:30">6:30</option>
<option value="7:00">7:00</option>
<option value="7:30">7:30</option>
<option value="8:00" >8:00</option>
<option value="8:30">8:30</option>
<option value="9:00">9:00</option>
<option value="9:30">9:30</option>
<option value="10:00">10:00</option>
<option value="10:30">10:30</option>
<option value="11:00">11:00</option>
<option value="11:30">11:30</option>
<option value="12:00">12:00</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30</option>
</select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <select ID="ddlSunEnd" runat="server" class="form-control">
<option value="Close">Closes at</option>
<option value="1:00">1:00</option>
<option value="1:30">1:30</option>
<option value="2:00">2:00</option>
<option value="2:30">2:30</option>
<option value="3:00">3:00</option>
<option value="3:30">3:30</option>
<option value="4:00">4:00</option>
<option value="4:30">4:30</option>
<option value="5:00">5:00</option>
<option value="5:30">5:30</option>
<option value="6:00">6:00</option>
<option value="6:30">6:30</option>
<option value="7:00">7:00</option>
<option value="7:30">7:30</option>
<option value="8:00" >8:00</option>
<option value="8:30">8:30</option>
<option value="9:00">9:00</option>
<option value="9:30">9:30</option>
<option value="10:00">10:00</option>
<option value="10:30">10:30</option>
<option value="11:00">11:00</option>
<option value="11:30">11:30</option>
<option value="12:00">12:00</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30</option>
</select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class=" col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="ChkMON" type="checkbox" value="Monday" runat="server" class="single mon option-input checkbox" name="days" /><span class="mon" style="font-size:20px;"> Monday</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="Mon" style="display:none;">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <select ID="ddlMonStart" runat="server" class="form-control">
<option value="start">Satrts at</option>
<option value="1:00">1:00</option>
<option value="1:30">1:30</option>
<option value="2:00">2:00</option>
<option value="2:30">2:30</option>
<option value="3:00">3:00</option>
<option value="3:30">3:30</option>
<option value="4:00">4:00</option>
<option value="4:30">4:30</option>
<option value="5:00">5:00</option>
<option value="5:30">5:30</option>
<option value="6:00">6:00</option>
<option value="6:30">6:30</option>
<option value="7:00">7:00</option>
<option value="7:30">7:30</option>
<option value="8:00" >8:00</option>
<option value="8:30">8:30</option>
<option value="9:00">9:00</option>
<option value="9:30">9:30</option>
<option value="10:00">10:00</option>
<option value="10:30">10:30</option>
<option value="11:00">11:00</option>
<option value="11:30">11:30</option>
<option value="12:00">12:00</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30</option>
</select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <select ID="ddlMonEnd" runat="server" class="form-control">
<option value="Close">Close at</option>
<option value="1:00">1:00</option>
<option value="1:30">1:30</option>
<option value="2:00">2:00</option>
<option value="2:30">2:30</option>
<option value="3:00">3:00</option>
<option value="3:30">3:30</option>
<option value="4:00">4:00</option>
<option value="4:30">4:30</option>
<option value="5:00">5:00</option>
<option value="5:30">5:30</option>
<option value="6:00">6:00</option>
<option value="6:30">6:30</option>
<option value="7:00">7:00</option>
<option value="7:30">7:30</option>
<option value="8:00" >8:00</option>
<option value="8:30">8:30</option>
<option value="9:00">9:00</option>
<option value="9:30">9:30</option>
<option value="10:00">10:00</option>
<option value="10:30">10:30</option>
<option value="11:00">11:00</option>
<option value="11:30">11:30</option>
<option value="12:00">12:00</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30</option>
</select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <br/>
              <button type="submit" id="btnCheckdays" class="btn btn-success">update</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect all messages in an array like so.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btnCheckdays").click(function(evt) {
      var msg = [];

      $("#showweekhours input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, el) {
        var day = $(el).val();
        var timesMsg = [];

        // selector for select fields in div with ids #Sun, #Mon, #Tue ...
        var daySelector = ["#showweekhours", " #", day.substring(0, 3), ' select'].join('');

        $(daySelector).each(function(i, sel) {
            var $sel = $(sel);
            var choiceTime = $sel.val();

            if (!["Satrt", "start", "Close", "Close at"].includes(choiceTime)) {
              if ($sel.attr('id').endsWith("Start")) {
                timesMsg.push(choiceTime);
              }

              if ($sel.attr('id').endsWith("End")) {
                timesMsg.push(choiceTime);
              }
            }
        });

        if (timesMsg.length == 2) {
          msg.push(["Day", day, "Start Time is:", timesMsg[0], "End Time is:", timesMsg[1]].join(" "));
        } else {
          msg.push(["Day", day, "Shop closed"].join(" "));
        }
    });

      alert(msg.join("\n"));

    });

  });
```

You can loop through `msg` if you'll like to show multiple alert boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to display closed next to the Check box when it's not selected..

```
var $dayBoxs = $('input[name=allChkBoxname]');

$dayBoxs.each(function(){
        // Do stuff here with this

  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
     alert("OPen");
  }
  else
  {
     alert("CLosed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use prop to check the checkBox is checked or not.

```
if ($ChkSUN.prop('checked')) {
 // do something
 alert('checked')
}else{
 // do this
 alert('not checked')
}
```

Comment: There's no variable called `$ChkSUN` ;)

Answer (score -1):

In your script you can do something like this

```js
var checked = $('.option-input:checked');
```

This will give you all of the elements that have the class option-input and that are checked.
Then you can wrap your alerts in a conditional to say..

```js
if (checked.length) {
    ... alert info
} else {
    alert('shops closed!');
}
```